# Where is the default max page size of GCP APIs documented?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Looking at the API reference I see there is no max page size described: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.jobs/list

But does that mean I can make the page as big as I want? Right now I make it arbitrarily large:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

discovery_service = discovery.build("dataflow", "v1b3", cache_discovery=False)

jobs = discovery_service.projects().locations().jobs().list(
    projectId=my_project,
    location="aggregated",
    pageSize=100000 # Is there any limit here?
).execute().get('jobs',[])

print(len(jobs))
```

I only have a few thousand jobs and it seems to be getting all of them, but I want to know if I can get away with this forever. Whenever I see a paginator for an API like this it always has some kind of limit to what it will return.

I'd rather set no limit like I am above because it's much simpler for what I need, but I don't trust the google docs. Is there really no limit at all, can this be confirmed?

Comment: Reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.jobs/list#query-parameters  ... I did find the following which seems to say that Google doesn't want to specify what the value of an upper bound is but acknowledges that there is one.

If there are many jobs, limit response to at most this many. The actual number of jobs returned will be the lesser of max_responses and an unspecified server-defined limit.

Comment: There are many factors that affect the maximum items returned. The transfer limits of proxies and load balancers, the size of the individual items, network reliability, etc. In general, I do not recommend setting a large value. Use the default values unless you want to spend time testing boundaries and bizarre one-off problems. What works today, might not work tomorrow if an item is extended with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is not an specified boundary the [`pageSize`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.jobs/list#query-parameters) definition is as follows:

> integer
>
> If there are many jobs, limit the response to at most this many. The actual number of jobs returned will be the lesser of max_responses and an unspecified server-defined limit.

There are other factors that affect the maximum number of items returned: The transfer limits of proxies and load balancers, the size of the individual items, network reliability, etc.

It might not be recommended to set a large value and instead use the default values with some exception scenarios. This to avoid the malfunctioning of an item that is extended with new data